# BeautifulSoup printing empty element

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn web scraping (and python) with beautifulsoup and selenium by scraping and storing pvp stats from a tracking website. The site I'm scraping has an element that displays your chance of winning a match, and I'm trying to grab that value. The issue is: it prints as a blank element ("[]"). I have tried using .text, but that throws an exception. I'm sure it's a simple fix, I'm just a little out of my depth. My full code is below and seems to be doing what I need it to do otherwise.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import codecs
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/bungie/4611686018453544077/overview")
html = driver.page_source

page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")

element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "match-row--expandable")

for i in element:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    close = driver.find_element_by_class_name("close")
    chance = page_soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'match-chance'})#pull match chance
    close.click()
    print(chance)

driver.close()
```

Comment: What is `chance.size()`? Are you trying to get the length of the `chance` element?

Comment: Oops, that was was in there by accident. Changed post to reflect actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to use bs4 for just one line. You might as well do with Selenium itself.
You can replace  `chance = page_soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'match-chance'})#pull match chance` with `chance = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'match-chance')` and you'd get some result.

Your code refactored:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import codecs
import time
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/bungie/4611686018453544077/overview")
# html = driver.page_source
# page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "match-row--expandable")

for i in element:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    # chance = page_soup.find('div', {'class' : 'match-chance'})#pull match chance
    chance = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'match-chance')
    print(chance.text)
    close = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "close")
    close.click()
driver.close()
```

Output:

```
Bravo had a 42% chance of winning!
Alpha had a 92% chance of winning!
Bravo had a 81% chance of winning!
Alpha had a 64% chance of winning!
Alpha had a 52% chance of winning!
Bravo had a 75% chance of winning!
```

Comment: Oh man! I didn't even know selenium could do that (I have very little idea what I'm doing). That works, I appreciate you so much!

Comment: @Zeggitt, please accept the answer if it works. Thank you